# How to use output of program A as input for B in bash?

Tags: c, bash

That is, `B` has a `gets` that asks for input, `A` has a `puts` that outputs something.

Both `A` and `B` are C programs.

How can I use the output of program A as input for B in bash?

What I tried is `./A |./B` and `./B |./A`, but neither works.

**UPDATE**

How does stuff in stdout of A goes to stdin of B for `./A|./B`?

Comment: You have to show what A and B is. `puts` and `gets` is not really `bash` commands

Comment: `puts` and `gets` are c statement.

Comment: gets and puts in c read/output from stdin..

Comment: Are there any sort of error messages that show up, or does it just silently fail?

Comment: Program B is buggy; so is any other program that uses `gets()`. Always use `fgets()` (or some other function where you can specifiy the size of the buffer available to receive the data).  **Never use `gets()`**.  Not even in toy programs.  Forget that `gets()` exists.  Replace `gets()` in your library with a function that aborts, so that any programs that use it crash under control before any damage is done. Fix Program B!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example to get you started:

```
/* a.c */
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    puts("This is a string");
    return 0;
}
```

Compile this as "a.out".

Here is the program that will catch the string from a.out:

```
/* b.c */
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char line[1024];
    fgets(line,1023,stdin);
    printf("b.c: %s",line);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile this as "b.out".

Now run them together:

```
./a.out | ./b.out
```

The main principle for pipes to work is that you write to stdout and read stdin. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Can you elaborate how stuff in stdout goes to stdin?

Comment: @compile-fan, Well a lot of things take place internally to make this happen. To simplify, a program has 3 standard streams, stdin for input (from keyboard), stdout for output (on screen) and stderr for error (on screen). You can change the streams to point to different locations ... like redirecting stdout to a file using ">". What internally happens is that the output stream of a.out is redirected to the input stream of b.out.